# How to add capable display driver to Lenovo G50 Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G50-45 80E301GUUS with AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics.  It has a clean Windows 8.1-32 bit installed on it (NOT the factory image...the drive partitions got wiped and Lenovo wants to charge for the CD which I refuse on principle).

The current display driver is not capable of sending the screen to another monitor:

> **Project**
>
> Your PC can't project to another screen. Try  reinstalling the driver or using a different video card.

In `Device Manager` it says `Microsoft Basic Display Adapter`, which is said to be up to date if I try the update (although the driver date is 6/21/2006!).

The Lenovo site does not offer a display driver for this machine (Windows 8.1 - 32 bit), that I can find.

The AMD site offers some drivers, but I have not been able to get any that are compatible.  I have tried radeon-crimson and amd-catalyst.  I managed to get to a list of drivers by using the "have disk" option, but there was no R5 6410 in the list, and the other R5's I tried came back with a message about not being compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install proper chipset driver first : http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Windows%208%20-%2064

Then install this driver : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

(amd-catalyst-15.11.1beta-32bit-win10-win8.1-win7-nov14.exe)

Comment: Before the install of 15.11.1 was even complete, the external monitor came alive!